# Asp net core Error 405 method not allowed on POST

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, saml

I have an asp net core application developed with .NET 5.

In this application, there is a controller (ACSController) that manages responses from an Identity Provider. The **controller** **is the follow**:

```
public class ACSController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRequestRepository _requestRepository;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private readonly IIdpRepository _idpRepository;
    private readonly IResponseRepository _responseRepository;

    private readonly AppSessionViewModel _session;

    public ACSController(IRequestRepository requestRepository, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
        IIdpRepository idpRepository, IResponseRepository responseRepository, AppSessionViewModel session)
    {
        _requestRepository = requestRepository;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        _idpRepository = idpRepository;
        _responseRepository = responseRepository;

        _session = session;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(IFormCollection form)
    {
        var base64Response = form["SAMLResponse"].ToString();
        var response = SAMLHelper.GetAuthnResponse(base64Response);

        var cachedRequest = _requestRepository.Read();
        var idpMetadata = await SamlHandler.DownloadIdPMetadata(_httpClientFactory,
            _idpRepository.Read().OrganizationUrlMetadata);

        var validationResult = ResponseValidator.ValidateAuthnResponse(response, cachedRequest, idpMetadata);

        if (validationResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            _responseRepository.Write(response);
            _session.Logged = true;
            ViewData["UserInfo"] = CreateUserInfo(response);
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = validationResult.Error;
            return View("Error");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Logout(IFormCollection form)
    {
        var base64Response = form["SAMLResponse"].ToString();
        return View();
    }

    

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }

    #region Utilities

    private Dictionary<string, string> CreateUserInfo(AuthnResponse response)
    {
        if (response == null) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(response));

        var attributes = response.GetAssertion().GetAttributeStatement().Items;

        var userDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            var attr = (AttributeType)attribute;
            userDictionary.Add(attr.Name, (string)attr.AttributeValue.First());
        }

        return userDictionary;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In my case, there is no problem when acs/index method is called by a POST request.

When I invoke the Logout procedure (from another controller) the request is sent correctly by my application but when IdP responds to me I obtain this response on my browser:
[https:///acs/logout?SAMLResponse=fVLBSsNAEL0L%2FYeS%2Bya72b …](https://acs/logout?SAMLResponse=fVLBSsNAEL0L%2FYeS%2Bya72b%20%E2%80%A6) with a 405 error.

This is my **Startup.cs** :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddSingleton<IRequestRepository, RequestRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IIdpRepository, IdpRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IResponseRepository, ResponseRepository>();

        services.AddSingleton<AppSessionViewModel>();
        
        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.Configure<Spid>(Configuration.GetSection("Spid"));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        //app.UseSession();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my launchSettings.json (I use SPID_Test as web browser):

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:15378",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

},

```
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}

"SPID_Test": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Comment: The browser is most likely making a GET request, which the controller is not designed to handle

Comment: Using [HttpGet] my controller is fired but the SAMLResponse seems not to be base64 string and my app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]` and then change `IFormCollection form` to `string SAMLResponse`.[Model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources) gets data from Query string parameters by default,so it can bind `string SAMLResponse` with `SAMLResponse=xxx` by default.Here is a demo:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Logout(string SAMLResponse)
        {
            var base64Response = SAMLResponse;
            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]

**Update：**

If you want to decode a base64string,try to use:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(SAMLResponse);
 string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: It seems to work. Now there is another problem because the string `SAMLResponse` is not a base64 string but I need a base64 string. Any idea?

Comment: The data depends on what you passed in url(`SAMLResponse=xxx`)?If you pass base64 string in url,`SAMLResponse`  will be a base64 string.

Comment: My problem is that `SAMLResponse` is sent by an Identity Provider and I need to "decode" it. The string is not made up by me.

Comment: I have updated my answer about how to decode a base64 string.

Comment: Now I obtain the following exception:
"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: Ok, the problem is about the Idp that I have used for tests. It ignores POST and send me a GET request but your answer is correct and allow my application to fire the action method using HttpGet so I can accept it. Thank you!